# Jquery Apprise Plugin not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, plugins, ready

here is my problem :)

i try to add "Apprise-v2" plugin to my website,
i include both files, css and js, this way :

```
<!--TOP OF MY PAGE-->
<html>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/apprise-v2.css"/>
<!--MY PAGE CONTENTS...-->
    ...........
<!--BOTTOM OF MY PAGE-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tablesorter/tables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script src='js/apprise-v2.js'></script>
    <script>Apprise("test");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my firebug warns me with this :

```
TypeError: $Apprise is null
if($Apprise.is(':visible')) {
```

Thanks for help! :)

EDIT : Here is the apprise-v2.js file contents :

```
// Global Apprise variables
var $Apprise = null,
$overlay = null,
$body = null,
$window = null,
$cA = null,
AppriseQueue = [];
// Add overlay and set opacity for cross-browser compatibility
$(function() {
    $Apprise = $('<div class="apprise">');
    $overlay = $('<div class="apprise-overlay">');
    $body = $('body');
    $window = $(window);
    $body.append( $overlay.css('opacity', '.94') ).append($Apprise);
});
function Apprise(text, options) {
    // Restrict blank modals
    if(text===undefined || !text) {
        return false;
    }
    // Necessary variables
    var $me = this,
    $_inner = $('<div class="apprise-inner">'),
    $_buttons = $('<div class="apprise-buttons">'),
    $_input = $('<input type="text">');
    // Default settings (edit these to your liking)
    var settings = {
        animation: 700, // Animation speed
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
            action: function() { $me.dissapear(); }, // Callback function
            className: null, // Custom class name(s)
            id: 'confirm', // Element ID
            text: 'Ok' // Button text
            }
        },
        input: false, // input dialog
        override: true // Override browser navigation while Apprise is visible
    };
    // Merge settings with options
    $.extend(settings, options);
    // Close current Apprise, exit
    if(text=='close') {
        $cA.dissapear();
        return;
    }
    // If an Apprise is already open, push it to the queue
    if($Apprise.is(':visible')) {
        AppriseQueue.push({text: text, options: settings});
        return;
    }
    // Width adjusting function
    this.adjustWidth = function() {
        var window_width = $window.width(), w = "20%", l = "40%";
        if(window_width<=800) {
            w = "90%", l = "5%";
        } else if(window_width <= 1400 && window_width > 800) {
            w = "70%", l = "15%";
        } else if(window_width <= 1800 && window_width > 1400) {
            w = "50%", l = "25%";
        } else if(window_width <= 2200 && window_width > 1800) {
            w = "30%", l = "35%";
        }
        $Apprise.css('width', w).css('left', l);
    };
    // Close function
    this.dissapear = function() {
        $Apprise.animate({
            top: '-100%'
        }, 
        settings.animation, function() {
            $overlay.fadeOut(300);
            $Apprise.hide();
            // Unbind window listeners
            $window.unbind("beforeunload");
            $window.unbind("keydown");
            // If in queue, run it
            if(AppriseQueue[0]) {
                Apprise(AppriseQueue[0].text, AppriseQueue[0].options);
                AppriseQueue.splice(0,1);
            }
        });
        return;
    };
    // Keypress function
    this.keyPress = function() {
        $window.bind('keydown', function(e) {
            // Close if the ESC key is pressed
            if(e.keyCode===27) {
                if(settings.buttons.cancel) {
                    $("#apprise-btn-" + settings.buttons.cancel.id).trigger('click');
                } else {
                    $me.dissapear();
                }
            } else if(e.keyCode===13) {
                if(settings.buttons.confirm) {
                    $("#apprise-btn-" + settings.buttons.confirm.id).trigger('click');
                } else {
                    $me.dissapear();
                }
            }
        });
    };
    // Add buttons
    $.each(settings.buttons, function(i, button) {
        if(button) {
            // Create button
            var $_button = $('<button id="apprise-btn-' + button.id + '">').append(button.text);
            // Add custom class names
            if(button.className) {
                $_button.addClass(button.className);
            }
            // Add to buttons
            $_buttons.append($_button);
            // Callback (or close) function
            $_button.on("click", function() {
                // Build response object
                var response = {
                    clicked: button, // Pass back the object of the button that was clicked
                    input: ($_input.val() ? $_input.val() : null) // User inputted text
                };
                button.action( response );
                //$me.dissapear();
            });
        }
    });
    // Disabled browser actions while open
    if(settings.override) {
        $window.bind('beforeunload', function(e){
            return "An alert requires attention";
        });
    }
    // Adjust dimensions based on window
    $me.adjustWidth();
    $window.resize( function() { $me.adjustWidth() } );
    // Append elements, show Apprise
    $Apprise.html('').append( $_inner.append('<div class="apprise-content">' + text + '</div>') ).append($_buttons);
    $cA = this;
    if(settings.input) {
        $_inner.find('.apprise-content').append( $('<div class="apprise-input">').append( $_input ) );
    }
    $overlay.fadeIn(300);
    $Apprise.show().animate({
        top: '20%'
        },
        settings.animation,
        function() {
            $me.keyPress();
        }
    );
    // Focus on input
    if(settings.input) {
        $_input.focus();
    }
} // end Apprise();
```

Comment: what's there in $Apprise..????

Comment: $Apprise is inside the apprise-v2.js file... it's a file i just included... no need to edit it... (i think!)
i add the file into edit in a few seconds

Comment: FireBug comes with this message : 
 

if($Apprise.is(':visible')) {

apprise-v2.js (ligne 48)
--(btw, thx for the "bad vote", i searched on the web about this problem, no clear solution that fixes it, and my question is clear!)--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make call after page loaded.

```
$(function() {
  Apprise('hi there');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, seems like it's working fine this way, i thought it would react like an alert, i can call an alert inside a document which is not fully loaded...!  Thanxx lots for help (even if it was easy :P )

Comment: Occurs asynchronous loading script. We must wait for the end of it boot

Answer (score 0):

I think using Apprise V3 is a better idea.
https://github.com/exis9/Apprise_V3

Comment: Ofc, after 7 years a new version is probably the best option !   thx